# SQL adding missing dates to query

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date-range

I'm trying to add missing dates to a SQL query but it does not work.

Please can you tell me what I'm doing wrong.
I only have read only rights to database.

SQL query:

```
With cteDateGen AS
(
  SELECT 0 as Offset, CAST(DATEADD(dd, 0, '2015-11-01') AS DATE) AS WorkDate
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Offset + 1, CAST(DATEADD(dd, Offset, '2015-11-05') AS DATE)
  FROM cteDateGen
  WHERE Offset < 100
), -- generate date from to --
cte AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() AS 'total' ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY c.dt DESC) as row
        , c.* 
    FROM clockL c
    RIGHT JOIN cteDateGen d ON CAST(c.dt AS DATE) = d.WorkDate
    WHERE 
        c.dt between '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-05' and
        --d.WorkDate BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-05' 
        and c.id =10
) -- select user log and add missing dates --  
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
--WHERE row BETWEEN 0 AND 15
--option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: What does not work mean? What is the error?

Comment: there is no error, but it does not add the missing dates

eg. 2015-11-01 to 2015-11-03 date range, missing date might be '2015-11-01' i need it to add the missing date, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is simply the dates in the CTE.  You can also simplify it a bit:

```
With cteDateGen AS (
      SELECT 0 as Offset, CAST('2015-11-01' AS DATE) AS WorkDate
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT Offset + 1, DATEADD(day, 1, WorkDate) AS DATE)
      -----------------------------------^
      FROM cteDateGen
      WHERE Offset < 100
     ), -- generate date from to --
     cte AS
      (SELECT COUNT(*) OVER () AS total,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.dt DESC) as row,
              c.* 
       FROM cteDateGen d LEFT JOIN
            clockL c
            ON CAST(c.dt AS DATE) = d.WorkDate AND c.id = 10
-----------------------------------------------^
       WHERE d.WorkDate between '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-05'
     ) -- select user log and add missing dates --  
SELECT * 
FROM cte
```

Notes:

- Your query used a constant for the second date in the CTE.  The constant was different from the first constant.  Hence, it was missing some days.
- I think that `LEFT JOIN` is much easier to follow than `RIGHT JOIN`.  `LEFT JOIN` is basically "keep all rows in the first table".
- The `WHERE` clause was undoing the outer join in any case.  The `c.id` logic needs to move to the `ON` clause.
- The date arithmetic in the first CTE was unnecessarily complex.

Comment: That was my first thought too, although I'm a little confused - why only move one of the conditions? Don't the remaining conditions in the where clause not also effectively make it into an inner join on a table where values are expected to be missing?

Comment: Now if it was `cteDateGen.WorkDate BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-05'` I'd be agreeing with you...

Comment: @Bridge . . . That should be the correct logic if you want to add dates.